# css borders as a decoaration

Tags: css, border

I'm trying to create something like this: http://yraveh.co.il/thefirm
on my WordPress site, theme avada.
What would be the easiest way to get such design?

Comment: The great thing about HTML/CSS is that you can see all of the source code!

Answer (score 0):

This is too broad a question to answer completely, but I would suggest creating two columns inside a container element. Then apply borders.

Your CSS might look something like this:

```css
.container {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.right-column {
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
```